# How to use a string returned from php by ajax as data for a chart.js chart?

Tags: javascript, ajax, chart.js

I have some php that queries the database and returns a string that looks like this if I view it in the console.

```
 datasets: [{label:'Crafting Ideas', borderColor: '#e6194b', fill: false, data: [{x:new Date(1523923200000),y:5},{x:new Date(1525305600000),y:3},{x:new Date(1526256000000),y:4},{x:new Date(1527811200000),y:3},] },{label:'Punctuation', borderColor: '#3e95cd', fill: false, data: [{x:new Date(1523923200000),y:5},{x:new Date(1525305600000),y:3},{x:new Date(1526256000000),y:4},{x:new Date(1527811200000),y:3},] },{label:'Text Forms & Features', borderColor: '#3cb44b', fill: false, data: [{x:new Date(1523923200000),y:5},{x:new Date(1525305600000),y:4},{x:new Date(1526256000000),y:4},{x:new Date(1527811200000),y:4},] },{label:'Vocabulary', borderColor: '#ffe119', fill: false, data: [{x:new Date(1523923200000),y:9},{x:new Date(1525305600000),y:8},{x:new Date(1526256000000),y:5},{x:new Date(1527811200000),y:6},] },{label:'Grammatical Accuracy', borderColor: '#0082c8', fill: false, data: [{x:new Date(1523923200000),y:6},{x:new Date(1525305600000),y:5},{x:new Date(1526256000000),y:4},{x:new Date(1527811200000),y:3},] },{label:'Group and Word Level Grammar', borderColor: '#3e95cd', fill: false, data: [{x:new Date(1523923200000),y:4},{x:new Date(1525305600000),y:4},{x:new Date(1526256000000),y:3},{x:new Date(1527811200000),y:5},] },{label:'Sentence Level Grammar', borderColor: '#911eb4', fill: false, data: [{x:new Date(1523923200000),y:6},{x:new Date(1525305600000),y:6},{x:new Date(1526256000000),y:6},{x:new Date(1527811200000),y:5},] },{label:'Whole Text Level Grammar', borderColor: '#46f0f0', fill: false, data: [{x:new Date(1523923200000),y:4},{x:new Date(1525305600000),y:3},{x:new Date(1526256000000),y:4},{x:new Date(1527811200000),y:1},] },{label:'Crafting Ideas', borderColor: '#f032e6', fill: false, data: [{x:new Date(1523923200000),y:5},{x:new Date(1525305600000),y:4},{x:new Date(1526256000000),y:4},{x:new Date(1527811200000),y:3},] },{label:'Spelling', borderColor: '#d2f53c', fill: false, data: [{x:new Date(1523923200000),y:5},{x:new Date(1525305600000),y:5},{x:new Date(1526256000000),y:4},{x:new Date(1527811200000),y:4},] },{label:'Handwriting', borderColor: '#3e95cd', fill: false, data: [{x:new Date(1523923200000),y:6},{x:new Date(1525305600000),y:4},{x:new Date(1526256000000),y:3},{x:new Date(1527811200000),y:3},] },{label:'Element Aggregate', borderColor: '#3e95cd', fill: false, data: [{x:new Date(1523923200000),y:62.5},{x:new Date(1525305600000),y:52.27},{x:new Date(1526256000000),y:46.59},{x:new Date(1527811200000),y:42.05},] },] },
```

When I paste this into my chart js, it renders a lovely chart. I'm very happy with it, but I can't get the datasets returned from ajax into my chart.js code. I have tried fooling around with global variables and moving the chart code into the success function but nothing seems to work.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
var studenttax = jQuery("div[id='student-tax']").attr('data');  

jQuery.ajax({
url  : 'https://goodatschool.com/writing/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php',
type : 'post',
data : {
action  : 'return_student_data',
studenttax : studenttax
},
success : function( response ) {   
chartfunction(response)
}

})
});

function chartfunction(val) {
var chartdata = val;
var chart = new Chart(document.getElementById('myChart'), {    
type: 'line',
data: val       
options: {      
    scales: {
        xAxes: [{
               type: 'time',
               time: {  unit: 'day',
                        distribution: 'linear',
                        displayFormats: {
                           'day': 'MMM DD',
                        }},              
          scaleLabel: {
            display: true,
            labelString: 'Date of Assessment'
          }
        }],
        yAxes: [{
            ticks: {
                min: 0,
                },
          scaleLabel: {
            display: true,                
            labelString: 'Percentage Score'
          }
        }] },
    title: {
    display: true,
    text: 'Student Writing Assessments',
},   
    legend: {
       display: true,
      position: 'bottom'
    }
 }
 });  

 }
```

This just returns the following in the inspector:

```
function chartfunction(val) {
var chartdata = val;
var chart = new Chart(document.getElementById('myChart'), {    
type: 'line',
data: chartdata     
options: {
```

Answer (score 0):

try

```
data: val.dataset.data
```

rather than

```
data: val
```

It appears you're just popping the entire json into the val field, rather than isolating the data portion needed for plotting

Comment: This achieves the same result. I don't think what is being returned is JSON but just a big string.

Comment: If it's just a string, then run val = json.parse(val), to parse the string into a json object

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that the response from php was actually a string. Chart() requires data to be an object, so constructing an array in php with relevant data and using json_encode() allowed the data property to be filled with values from the server.